# contents of combo box shown in list box

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2003

I was wondering, if I click a selection on a `ComboBox` for instance letter `A`, and I want its content to show in `label` or `ListBox`, how can I do that? I tried experimenting with some codes below. This codes below are not working for me. any other way or suggestion?

```
    private void selectContents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string var;
        var = selectContents.Text;

        if (var == "A")
        {
            Label1.Text = "hi";
            listBox1.Text = "hi";

        }
    }
```

ok problem solve i just need to change the var :D

Comment: you can't have string var   , var is a keyword in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have `string var;`

`var` is a keyword in c#  [MSDN C# keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I have no clue how that code was compiling, I suppose it wasn't

**edit**

```
string a = "var";    //this is ok
string var = "a";    //this is not
```

Comment: oww i see but i was able to use this in one of my combo box??oww i know now. i just changed the var with another name

Comment: it can be a value of a property, but not the name of it

Comment: oww i know now. i just changed the var with another name. thanks

Comment: @kazSone - mark as answered if this solves your problem to help future visitors

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
private void selectContents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(selectContents.SelectedItem);
    Label1.Text = selectContents.SelectedItem;
}
```